# remove title,tooltip,tooltipenable from jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to know how can I remove the title,tooltip,tooltipenable attribute from a jquery ui datepicker so that it will also not show as a tooltip when click on next and previous on datepicker. Below is the code

```
$("#startDate").datepicker(
        { beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var day = date.getDay();
         var date1 = date.getDate();
         var today = new Date();
         var difference = date - today;
         var daysDifference = Math.round(difference/(1000*60*60*24));         
          if(daysDifference < 0) {
                 return [false]
         }else{
           return [true]
         }

          }
        });

    $( "#startDate").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd" );
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({ minDate: '+0m +0w +1d'});
```

I have tried this but no use:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all").removeAttr("title");
$(".ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all").removeAttr("title");
```

in html

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_1430805360315.datepicker._adjustDate('#startDate', +1, 'M');" tooltip="Next" tooltipenable="true">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
</a>
```

How can I remove them. Thanks

Comment: this selector is wrong $(".ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all").removeAttr("title");

Comment: it should be $(".ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all")

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Thanks, I have one more question how can I can I get an event of next and previous in order to remove an attribute?

Comment: Thanks I have done it

Answer (score 2):

If you need to hide only tooltip then you can add empty text in `prevText`, `nextText` options, empty title won't show in default tooltip, try this code

```js
$(function() {
  $("#startDate").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      var date1 = date.getDate();
      var today = new Date();
      var difference = date - today;
      var daysDifference = Math.round(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      if (daysDifference < 0) {
        return [false]
      } else {
        return [true]
      }

    }
  });

  $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
  $("#startDate").datepicker({
    minDate: '+0m +0w +1d'
  });
  $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "prevText", "");
  $("#startDate").datepicker("option", "nextText", "");
})
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="startDate">
```

Comment: Thanks Girish. I am also using mbTooltip for it. what I want is to disable mbTooltip.js only for the datepicker. I think I have to disable this attribute as well "tooltipenable" as you can also see in the html section of my question